# Why html tags inside split gets altered when loaded with ajax into another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, split

look at this link

http://www.infopunta.com/test1/1stajax.asp

that page just loads with ajax another page with other javascript on it.

open it with firefox or chrome click inspect element and look at the ajax function loaded inside the body

in the split method that it haves says:

```
var partes = data.split("<pagebreak ></pagebreak>");
```

and the real line in the original file loaded says:

```
var partes = data.split("<pagebreak />");
```

you can see the original file here:  http://www.infopunta.com/test1/2ndajax.asp

somehow the TAGS inside javascript content loaded with ajax gets auto-closed.  And I don't want that!!

how can I fix this??

Comment: As an off-top question: is that a modern attitude to start sentences with small letter?

Comment: Why does it matter if they get auto closed? It has no real impact.

Comment: Yes it is, because I need that tag as it is, .

Your right VisionN